# What does thread local mean in Flask framework?

Tags: python, web-services, scalability, flask

I am evaluating python frameworks to build a REST API. I have gone through many frameworks including flask and found Flask pretty interesting and easy to use with all the features needed to build a REST web service.

One thing i don get is in flask docs it is mentioned that it uses "thread local and has issues with scalability".

> Flask uses thread local objects (context local objects in fact, they
>   support greenlet contexts as well) for request, session and an extra
>   object you can put your own things on (g). Why is that and isn’t that
>   a bad idea? Yes it is usually not such a bright idea to use thread
>   locals. They cause troubles for servers that are not based on the
>   concept of threads and make large applications harder to maintain.
>   However Flask is just not designed for large applications or
>   asynchronous servers. Flask wants to make it quick and easy to write a
>   traditional web application.

Can someone help me understand this, what scalability issues is being mentioned and how other frameworks handle this??

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a scalability issue, rather it can make it more difficult to maintain a complex code-base. This is because thread locals are used as a global data store, to avoid passing state via function arguments, which makes it harder to follow what's going on.

Speed-wise, thread locals are not particularly slow, but they do make it hard or impossible to use an asynchronous framework, where lots of tasks run for short amounts of time on a single thread.

Comment: So do you mean there are two separate problems with thread locals: (1) the programmer has to think about the state of the variables which makes it very hard to program; and (2) commonly used asynchronous programming frameworks won't work at all in the presence of thread locals?